# JQuery check which is the third visible element in a scrollable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, visible

I have a scrollable DIV. I want to know which is the third visible element. Unfortunately the JQuery:visible selector does not account for what cannot actually be seen on screen after a scroll.

```
function test() {
    alert($('#leftwheel li:visible').first().next().next().attr('title'));
}
```

This does not work as as far as Jquery is concerned the elements li is still visible, we need it to calculate based on what cannot be seen because it is now scrolled away.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: How does your scrolling script work? Does it hide the element, use overflow:hidden or what? Could you share that script as well please.

Comment: I am afraid it is a lowly scrolling div. no code

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the height of the `div` and the height of the list items.

Divide div-height by height of list item, which will give you the number of visible list items.

If this number is more than 3, then just take the third list item `$("div li").eq(2);`

Comment: Let me give a better example. Take a look at this fiddle. I want to know what the titles are of the LI in the middle http://jsfiddle.net/XHPYF/1